# Wiener Linien Day ticket (5.5 Euro)

Tags: public-transport, tickets, vienna

1. If I purchase a Wiener Linien Day ticket (5.5 Euros), can I travel in all buses and U-Bahn, S-Bahn trams (including Vienna Ring Tram) throughout the network? Just wanted to confirm.
2. Do we need to validate these?
3. Where can I buy these?

Comment: yes, yes (once), everywhere.

Comment: No, you can't use the Vienna Ring Tram.

Comment: @martin.koeberl That's true, but it's probably worth pointing out that you can use the other non-tourist trams that go around the Ringstraße (although you have to change to get all the way round). You miss out on 25 minutes of recorded commentary, but personally I didn't think that commentary was worth €9 anyway.

Comment: @chx Are you sure that those are available everywhere? From the Wiener Linien page it seems as they were only available online or via the app (The translation of the german ticket name also is "mobile day ticket"). See for example https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-47643

Comment: If I were sure I would've written an answer with sources. Comments are comments.

Comment: "all buses" also don't cover the tourist Hop-on-off buses.

Answer (score 5):

From the [ticket guide](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-47643) it seems as if the day ticket is only available in the Wiener Linien app, or in the [mobile online shop](https://shop.wienerlinien.at/mobile.php/). Since the ticket is only listed as a [mobile ticket](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-2000347), I'm fairly confident that this answer is correct. For example you can't find the ticket in the [online shop](https://shop.wienerlinien.at/index.php/tickets). Note also that as of January 1, 2018, this ticket costs €5,80.

When you buy the ticket, you have to enter the name of the person using it, and the date on which it should be valid. So there's no need (and also no way, since the ticket is on your phone) of validating the ticket. Whether you have to activate it (or something), I don't know, but I guess the app would tell you so.

If you prefer to get a ticket on paper which is also transferable, you could think about getting a [24-hour ticket (or 48-, or 72-)](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-2000560), which as the name says, is valid for 24 (48, 72) hours once it's validated. Another option would be the [Wiener Einkaufskarte](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-47398) (Vienna shopping ticket), which is only usable Mondays to Saturdays, and once validated is valid until 8pm of the same day (but only after 8am). (Wiener Linien stopped selling Wiener Einkaufskarte on January 1, 2018)

These are available almost everywhere: According to the [ticket folder](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/downloadTracker.do/path/media/files/2016/ticketangebot_183700.pdf?oid=68911&type=pdf) (PDF in german) you can get them at [info offices](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-2000644), [ticket offices](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-2000644), in the app, in the (mobile) online shop, or at tobacconists/newsagents/newsstands (I'm not sure whether that's an appropriate translation, but that's what the dictionary says; they are called Trafik in Austria).

Another option is an 8 day ticket (8-Tage-Klimakarte), which is good for 8 days (in fact, it's valid until 1am of the following day). However, you can also use it for two or more persons to travel on one day (by validating the appropriate number of lines on the ticket). For this, you just fold the ticket above the line you want to validate, and push it with the line you want to validate facing up in the validator. Empty lines below will be validated by this automatically. The tickets are available at the same places as the 24-hour ticket but not in the app or in the mobile shop.

If you come to Vienna as a tourist, you might be interested in the [Vienna card](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-47401) which is valid for 24, 48 or 72 hours (but not transferable). It also offers discounts at museums and other places, and according to [Wien Info](https://www.wien.info/en/sightseeing/sights/vienna-ring-tram) also gets you a cheaper ticket for the Vienna Ring Tram (more on that later), but I couldn't find out how much exactly. These tickets are available at the info offices, the ticket offices, online, at the airport, Vienna main station and some other places.

All of the tickets from Wiener Linien are valid on all underground lines, all tram lines, except Vienna Ring Tram, and buses operated by Wiener Linien (or their partners). You can recognize these buses by their line number ending in A or B. Within Vienna, you can also use the ticket on the Badner Bahn, and trains operated by ÖBB (for example S-Bahn). So, the tickets are not valid on, e.g.,  CAT (city airport train), tourist hop-on-hop-off buses, the Vienna Ring Tram, and certain bus lines.

For the [Vienna Ring Tram](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-47394) you have to buy an extra ticket which currently costs [€9](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66533/channelId/-47394). However, as was pointed out in the comments, you can travel on the same route without the audio comments. For example, starting at *Karlsplatz, Oper* you can take line 1 in direction *Prater Hauptallee* to *Schwedenplatz*. There you could take tram line 2 in direction *Dornbach* back to where you started.

Comment: Great answer! Regarding translation of "Trafik" -- if I were talking to a UK English speaker, I might say [newsagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newsagent%27s_shop#United_Kingdom), but I think there is no perfect equivalent. Probably if advising a tourist I would just say "Trafik" because then they know what word to look for on the sign :).

Comment: Too minor to edit in myself, but Wiener Linien buses on which these tickets can be used end in both A and B, not just A.